# Is it possible to twist bones while posing on Weight Painting mode?

Tags: bones

On regular pose mode, I can twist the forearm by changing the rotation value under Transform. But I can't use this method on Weight Painting mode, any value I change in Rotation moves the whole mesh. I can still pose the arm by grabbing the control bone, but I can't do twisting motions, just bending.

Comment: You can combine pose-mode and weight-paint mode, just tested this and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can. Just hit <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd>.

The Transform values in Properties panel refer to the mesh as it is the active object from those 2 selected while Weight Painting.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly as far as I know.

You can, however, animate the rig and scrub the timeline while in Weight Painting mode. This is optimal since you can easily go back and forth between few key poses while you paint.